# Minikube installation

Tags: minikube

After installing minikube when I chek the status,there isn't any host apiserver on ubuntu and kubeconfiguration plss suggest solution

There should be host running kubelet running alongwith configuration

Comment: Did you run `minikube start`?

Answer (score 0):

With Minikube, the Kubernetes piece runs inside of the Minikube container.  You'll want to connect to the minikube container via: "minikube ssh" and then check for the running kubelet.